# Terraform API gateway integration with Swagger (Localstack)

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, terraform, aws-api-gateway, localstack

i created a simple crud API lambda using mongoDb and nodeJs and it's working fine. so i passed to another step 
I'm currently creating an AWS API Gateway with terraform by using an open api spec from a yaml file.
this is my swagger file:

```
info:
  description: "API Ankan-v2"
  version: "V0.0.1"
  title: "ANKAN V2 API"
host: "localhost:4567"
basePath: "/restapis/api/{apiId}/test/_user_request_"
tags:
  - name: "user"
    description: "Operations about user"
schemes:
  - "http"
#    - "https"
paths:
  /documents/{documentId}:
    get:
      tags:
        - "document"
      summary: "Find document by ID"
      description: "Returns a single document"
      operationId: "readOneDocument"
      produces:
        - "application/json"
      parameters:
        - name: "documentId"
          in: "path"
          description: "Id of document"
          required: true
          type: "string"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Document"
        404:
          description: "document not found"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: ${get_lambda_arn}
        passthroughBehavior: "WHEN_NO_MATCH"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "AWS_PROXY"
    options:
      consumes:
        - "application/json"
      produces:
        - "application/json"
      parameters:
        - name: "documentId"
          in: "path"
          description: "Id of document"
          required: true
          type: "string"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Document"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        type: "mock"
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      produces:
        - "application/json"
      parameters:
        - name: "documentId"
          in: "path"
          description: "Id of document"
          required: true
          type: "string"
      responses: {}
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        uri: ${get_lambda_arn}
        passthroughBehavior: "WHEN_NO_MATCH"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        cacheNamespace: "1rnijn"
        cacheKeyParameters:
          - "method.request.path.documentId"
        type: "AWS"
definitions:
  Document:
    type: "object"
    required:
      - "documentName"
      - "documentPath"
      - "miniature"
      - "status"
      - "date"
    properties:
      _id:
        type: "string"
        readOnly: true
      documentName:
        type: "string"
      documentPath:
        type: "string"
      miniature:
        type: "string"
      status:
        type: "string"
        enum:
          - "VALID"
          - "ERROR"
          - "ONLOAD"
      date:
        type: "string"
        format: "date"
    xml:
      name: "Document"
```

in my terraform i removed the integration and the method because i added them in my swagger .
so i need to import the swagger file in aws_api_gateway_rest_api with `body = data.template_file.swagger.rendered`

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name = "api-gateway"
  description = "document api"
  body = data.template_file.swagger.rendered

}


data "template_file" "swagger" {
  template = jsonencode("${path.module}/../../../../shared/swagger.yaml")

  vars = {
    get_lambda_arn = local.get_lambda_arn
  }
}
output "json" {
  value = data.template_file.swagger.rendered
}

locals {
  get_lambda_arn = aws_lambda_function.lambda_document.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "documents" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "documents"
  depends_on  = [aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "document_by_id" {
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.documents.id
  path_part   = "{documentId}"
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "ApiDeloyment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  stage_name = "INT"

  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api]
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_document" {
  function_name = "lambda_document"
  handler = "lambda.handler"
  role = "arn:aws::iam::123456:role/irrelevant"
  runtime = "nodejs10.x"
  filename = "${path.module}/lambda.zip"

  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${path.module}/lambda.zip")
}
```

After terraform apply i got this message in terraform logs

```
terraform apply --auto-approve
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Creating...
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_lambda_function.lambda_document: Creating...
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_lambda_function.lambda_document: Creation complete after 5s [id=lambda_document]
module.backend_api.module.document.data.template_file.swagger: Refreshing state...
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
module.backend_api.module.document.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
```

and my docker-compose logs show this

```
localstack        | 2020-01-13T07:37:56:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack        |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 242, in forward
localstack        |     path=path, data=data, headers=forward_headers)
localstack        |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/apigateway/apigateway_listener.py", line 53, in forward_request
localstack        |     data = data and json.loads(to_str(data))
localstack        |   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
localstack        |     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
localstack        |   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
localstack        |     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
localstack        |   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
localstack        |     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
localstack        | json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

PS : i tried with JSON but same problem

is there any solution for this? i want to integrate swagger with api gateway using terraform in localstack

Comment: Does it work against "real" AWS?

Comment: No i didn't try it , i'am using aws with localstack .

Comment: This does appear to be a AWS limitation.

Comment: i don't think so , because it works with aws cli , in my situation i want to use terraform and localstack with code instead of aws cli.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the moto library. Under the hood, local stack uses moto to create its resources, including mock api gateway. Unfortunately moto does not currently support the body parameter for putting a swagger file definition as part of api gateway deployment. So even if you give a valid swagger file and api gateway configuration (ie one that works in aws) localstack will not be able to build it.